Checking mezuzos – must they be replaced from the same place from which they were taken
I have seen that people when taking down mezuzos to check them, label them to put them back in the same place from which they were taken. I could understand doing this for an area where the requirement for the mezuza is in doubt see here and the mezuza being used there is not top-quality.
Other than this case, what is the source that makes it necessary to put the mezuza back in the same place from which it was taken?

https://mezuzahmaven.org/returning-mezuzot-to-their-prior-locations-2/

@shmosel Yes. Can you please write it up as the answer?

According to the website Mezuzah Maven, it's about preserving their obligatory status:

One honors a mitzvah by taking care not to downgrade its status.
Therefore, if a mezuzah is proudly fulfilling its mission on a doorway
that is fully obligated, some authorities write that one should not
remove it to place it on a doorway which is questionably obligated.
For example, a mezuzah removed from a doorway fitted with a door
should not be placed on a doorway that has no door.
They also write that a mezuzah taken from a door obligated from Torah
law should not be “demoted” to a door that is obligated Rabbinically.
An example of this would be removing a mezuzah from a home that one
owns to be affixed to a door in a rental residence.
However, this practice is not mentioned by the Shulchan Aruch and
other classical authorities. Consequently, some authorities suggest
that if mezuzot are taken down to be checked or for another reason,
returning them to their original door would be praiseworthy but not
obligatory.

See there for sources.
